# How to select max value from rows and join to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, google-bigquery

I am trying to join two tables with respect to the max values for the values column. I would like to produce the expected results as shown below based on the max value while joining

```
select * from order
-------------------------
| ID    |  value | Name |
-------------------------
|  1    |  23    | REM  |
|  2    |  0     | SER  |
|  3    |  13    | MH   |
|  4    |  3     | MH   |
|  5    |  1     | MP   |
-------------------------

select * from product
-------------------------
| ID    | value  | Name |
-------------------------
|  1    |   2    | ABC  |
|  2    |  2    | DEG  |
|  3    |  17    | XYZ  |
-------------------------

Desired result:
-------------------------
| ID    | Value  | Name |
-------------------------
| 1     |  23    | REM  |
| 2     |  2    | DEG  |
| 3     |  17    | XYZ  |
| 4     |   3    | MH   |
| 5     |   1    | MP   |
-------------------------
```

I have tried something like below but it's not fetching the value (NAME) from other table

```
SELECT
 MAX(IF(a.value >b.value , a.value ,b.value )) AS Value
  from order a left join product b on a.ID= b.ID
```

Please suggest how to get the expected result from these two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardsql
select as value array_agg(struct(id, value, name) order by value desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from 
(
  select * from `project.dataset.order`
  union all
  select * from `project.dataset.product`
)
group by id
```

with output

[image]

Comment: just want to check - are you just ordering based on value ? without comparing value with other table ?

Comment: As i mentioned in question - i want to compare with other table and take the max value

Comment: that is exactly how it is. do you see it does not do this way? provide example then :o)

Comment: just modified the sample in question

Comment: still works for me - getting expected result - what the problem you see?

Comment: My question is - in your query , where are we comparing the values from two tables ? Sorry to ask some basic question since i am new to this

Comment: it is done because you union table1 with table2 so the max value is taken for given id. can you clarify though - are you getting expected result?!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a `full join`:

```
select id,
       (case when p.val is null or p.val < o.val then o.val else p.val end),
       (case when p.val is null or p.val < o.val then o.name else p.name end)     
from product p full join
     order o
     using (id);
```

I just find this the simplest way to think about the problem.